# Allow acf_form on my theme's single.php to run jQuery functions?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I have an ACF form that's on my theme's single.php to add URLs to load into a video player. It's a flexible content with two text fields and a button. One field is for entering a YouTube URL and the other is for extracting the URL and making in to other URL. The button group is for running a jQuery function.

When I click on the button, it doesn't run the function until I save the form. If I have a button outside the form, I can run the function without saving the field.

Are there ways to run a jQuery function in an ACF form?

The jQuery function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $('#yt_preview .acf-input .acf-button-group').click(function() {
      var yt_url_raw = document.querySelector('.acf-fields div.acf-field.acf-field-text.acf-field-6436f073d637e div.acf-input div.acf-input-wrap input');
      $(".acf-fields div.acf-field.acf-field-text.acf-field-6436f1ff96408").css({'display':'block'});
      $(".acf-fields div.acf-field.acf-field-text.acf-field-6436f073d637e").css({'display':'none'});
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Using .on made it work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $(document).on( "click", '#yt_preview .acf-input .acf-button-group', function(e) {
      $(".acf-fields div.acf-field.acf-field-text.acf-field-6436f1ff96408").css({'display':'block'});
      $(".acf-fields div.acf-field.acf-field-text.acf-field-6436f073d637e").css({'display':'none'});
   })
})
```